# How to open %AppData%\Nutshell.mdf in LINGPad

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to LINGPad 5. After installing it, I tried connecting to my SQL server. It was successful. Could anyone tell me how to open %AppData%\Nutshell.mdf in LINGPad?

TIA
Ben

Comment: Do you mean LINQPad by any chance? Also you'd open that database file in your database server, not the client application, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Yes It should be LINQPad rather than LINGPad.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing SQLExpress, the problem was solved.